# Unable to download three.js file using bower

Tags: javascript, git, three.js, bower, bower-install

I.m getting an error when I try to download three.js file by specifying the version in bower.json file.

```
 "dependencies": {
                 "three.js":"~0.0.69"
                }
```

> Error :No versions found in git://github.com/jiyinyiyong/three.js.git

Instead ,I'm downloading the whole repo by specifying the url like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
                      "three.js":"https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git"
                    }
```

which is taking time and space.
How can I download only the file from the git repo.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the period in three.js, i.e.

```
"dependencies": {
  "threejs": "r70"
}
```

This points to the official ThreeJS repository.

If you wish to only have the minified library file (much smaller download), use:

```
"dependencies": {
  "threejs": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.min.js"
}
```

Comment: @Brendan.Does it downloads the entire repository or only the files?

Comment: The entire repository.

Comment: But I want to download only the files

Comment: Updated answer to include minified file only

Comment: As far as I can tell, the update on this post is wrong. it still doesn't ignore the rest of the repository. I'm getting a huge download when running the install command.

Comment: @bzuillsmith it's actually been very inconsistent with my projects, I'm not 100% sure when or how it does the full or small download.

Comment: @BrendanAnnable Ah, you are in fact, correct. What happens is Bower installs the ENTIRE repository and then removes the ignored files. Which means you download 128MB of three.js stuff and it removes all but ~2.7MB (the dist files and samples)

Answer (score 2):

Simply run `bower install three.js` in your terminal.
Three will be installed to: *.../bower_components/three.js*

Answer (score 1):

The three.js package registered in the bower registry is pointing to https://github.com/jiyinyiyong/three.js which is not the official repo of three.js. This repository contains only 2 .js files: `three.js` and `three.min.js`.
The reason bower is not seeing any version is because this repository does not contain any tags (which bower use for versions). The latest version is in the master branch. If you like to install the latest version from the master branch, you should define the dependency as:

```
"dependencies": {
    "three.js": "master"
}
```

Notice that depending on a branch has some downsides as it may change (and probably will) in the future.